# which port should I connect to selenium in docker inside devContainer

Tags: javascript, docker, selenium, testing, vscode-devcontainer

In devContainer installed selenium chrome-standlone in docker which is running on localhost:4444. In the overview page, URI:http://172.17.0.2:4444. But I tried connect both localhost and 172.17.0.2 from my test eg. `new Builder().usingServer("http://172.17.0.2:4444").forBrowser("chrome").setChromeOptions(getOptions()).build();`. None of the port connect to the selenium grid. I do not know which port should I use to connect the selenium in docker.

Comment: What error do you exactly get?

Comment: @m19v, if localhost, I get "ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444", if 172.17.0.2, I get timeout of test

Comment: It seems, the path is not correct, example path: ```=http://www.example.com:4444/wd/hub ```, i.e. ```/wd/hub/``` is missing.

Comment: according to the doc, ```/wd/hub/``` is no longer needed

Comment: Do you see if the port is forwarded to your host machine?

Comment: I think the port is forwarded because localhost:4444 is running on my lost machine. In fact, I solve this issue by adding selenium-chrome-standlone onto docker-compose file of  dev-container.